# SQL: Delete almost duplicate rows that differ at most x seconds in timestamp and keep the oldest

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with a bunch of string attributes and a timestamp. The primary key consists of 4 string attributes and the timestamp. Rows are generated by parsing log messages. Unfortunately, one event creates several log messages with identical content except timestamp, which differs by a few seconds. So now I have a lot of rows which are identical in every attribute but timestamp and all timestamps lie in a 15 second interval. I want to delete all 'duplicate' (duplicate here meaning all attributes are equal except timestamp and timestamp differs by at most 15 seconds) rows except the one with the oldest timestamp.

Postgres version is 9.6.

I was able to write a query showing me all such 'duplicate' pairs, but I'm stumped in coming up with a solution to delete all but the oldest row. I could not adapt any of the solutions for duplicate deletion here on stackoverflow either. Probably need something with group by and delete * from interlock where not in (select min(timestamp)...):

Query showing 'duplicate' pairs:

```
select * 
from interlock i1
inner join interlock i2
on
i1.A = i2.A and
i1.B = i2.B and
i1.C = i2.C and
i1.D = i2.D and
i1.E = i2.E and
i1.F = i2.F and
i1.G = i2.G and
i1.H = i2.H and
i1.I = i2.I and
i1.J = i2.J and
i1.K = i2.K and
i1.timestamp <> i2.timestamp and
abs(extract(epoch from i1.timestamp) - extract(epoch from i2.timestamp)) < 15;
```

Comment: In that case, why is the timestamp used as a PK?

Comment: @kishore: The assumption was that there would be only one log message per event. I have no idea why there are so many, but I can't change it anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up using:

```
delete from interlock i1
where exists
(select 1 from interlock i2 
where i2.room = i1.room
and i2.interlock_device = i1.interlock_device
and i2.interlock_name = i1.interlock_name
and i2.title = i1.title
and i2.information = i1.information
and i2.explanation = i1.explanation
and i2.interlock_id = i1.interlock_id
and i2.error_id = i1.error_id
and i2.severity = i1.severity
and i2.acknowledged = i1.acknowledged
and i2.target = i1.target
and i2.timestamp < i1.timestamp
and i2.timestamp + interval '15 second' > i1.timestamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `delete`:

```
delete from interlock i
    from interlock i2
    where i2.a = i.a and . . .
          i2.timestamp > i.timestamp and
          i2.timestamp < i.timestamp + interval '15 second';
```

Comment: I get a syntax error on interlock for the line 'delete interlock i'.

Answer (score 0):

I think currently the best approach here would be to use the `USING` keyword.

I would re-write your code like this:

```
DELETE FROM interlock i1
USING interlock i2
WHERE i2.room = i1.room
AND i2.interlock_device = i1.interlock_device
AND i2.interlock_name = i1.interlock_name
AND i2.title = i1.title
AND i2.information = i1.information
AND i2.explanation = i1.explanation
AND i2.interlock_id = i1.interlock_id
AND i2.error_id = i1.error_id
AND i2.severity = i1.severity
AND i2.acknowledged = i1.acknowledged
AND i2.target = i1.target
AND i2.timestamp > i1.timestamp - 15 * interval '1 second'
AND i2.timestamp < i1.timestamp + 15 * interval '1 second';
```